# No responsive MacBook air

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, screen, startup

Tried starting in the morning after power drained, plugged in, everything came back for a few seconds then the screen went black. Can't restart. If I hold powe button down 10 sec machine emits an intermittent beep which continues until I push power button again. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Have you tried letting it charge for a while?

Comment: Unplug all except the power charger.

Comment: Does the pattern of beeps match one of the [descriptions in this Apple document about "startup tones"](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5860?viewlocale=en_US)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your system is stuck in the completely empty battery mode (warning tone).

Try holding the cmd+r after you pushed the power button.

or

To completely reset it, remove power and [disconnect the battery](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing+MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2011+Battery/6359/1), then reinstall.